# Keyword location in URL permalink structure effect on SEO

Tags: seo, url, keywords, permalinks

I am in the process of a large rebuild and redesign of my real estate website. Through this process, I am expanding my content and number of internal pages which are structured as Wordpress custom post types with category archives. I am at a decision point with permalink structure for my site and can choose two different directions to go, not sure which is best or if there is any impact on SEO for the two options. Most of it comes down to location of keyword search terms being placed in the permalink structures.

Is there any difference in SEO power for the following keywords whether they are placed all at the end of the permalink, versus being distributed more throughout the entire link address depth when there is a hierarchy and some keywords are in the domain name, partly in the category name, sub category name, and partly in the post slug of the link?

Since I have one of the keywords in my main domain, is it redundant and not necessary to have it in the post slug ending as well?

Either way in terms of number of clicks or depth to get to the targeted page, it would be the same regardless of how the permalink is structured.

Which of these would be better for SEO?
Keywords: grayhawk, scottsdale, arizona

- Option 1 (category-subcategory-post slug):  dwell**arizona**.com/luxury/**scottsdale/grayhawk**
- Option 2 : dwell**arizona**.com/luxury/**grayhawk-scottsdale-arizona**

Answer (score 1):

Does scottsdale has more posts related to it or is it just a component of the slug? Will there ever be

- `dwellarizona.com/luxury/scottsdale/post1`
- `dwellarizona.com/luxury/scottsdale/post2`

Then go with **Option1**.

If Scottsdale won't have more posts , then you would need another page there to not show a 404 error page or display something that won't be so natural in the URL hierarchy, in this case go with **Option 2**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it improves rank, but only then the user is searching with that Keyword.

I tested this with my jobs website. I have two posts:

- No location: `/cts-cognizant-walkin/`
- With location: `/cognizant-walkin-interview-for-freshers-hyderabad/`

Comment: I've edited this post to remove the keyword links to your website.     I think  you have something valuable to say, so I did not delete this entirely.  You could make this answer better by explaining more about what kinds of traffic you observed during your test.

Answer (score 0):

Each category and sub category will have it's own page.

dwellarizona.com/luxury will be it's own page with applicable SEO focused on a large market segment, and have links to different cities of which Scottsdale is one.

dwellarizona.com/luxury/scottsdale will be it's own page focused on the city of Scottsdale and luxury market, and have links to different neighborhoods of which grayhawk is one.

dwellarizona.com/luxury/scottsdale/grayhawk is a neighborhood page.